# Moving an Agent with a Resource

Tags: anylogic

I would like to have a pool of resources (Capacity 1) to transport parts within a room.

A Pool of resources is created in the "Job Shop" tutorial to transport boxes from a Pallet Rack to some machines. The block used is "Rack pick" which has the "Use Resources to Move" tool, very intuitive. When some box is requested, the resource transport it to the machine.

I'm looking for this "Use Resource to Move" in other blocks but I can't find it. How can I do this if I want to transport the box with a resource between two point nodes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a (seize + moveTo + release) blocks.

With the seize block you define the resource to use.
With the move to block you move your agent... it will move with the resource
With the release block you make the resource free again

Of course all these blocks have other options that you can use to make everything more specific, but this is the basic thing you should do.

In the process modeling library, the use resource to move option only exists in the racks, for anything else you have to use service or seize+release

Comment: Thank you Felipe. I did it the way you said and it worked.